# ERROR 000840: The value is not a Raster|Raster Catalog|Mosaic Layer from arcpy.AddJoin_management()?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.0, error-000840

I am doing some arcpy -functions and afterwards I'm trying to add the calculated results from one table to another table. I'm using the `arcpy.AddJoin_management()` function.

As input table I'm using a table which is stored in a personal geodatabase. The personal geodatabase is not the workspace environment! As "JoinTable" a Table of a file geodatabase is used. This file geodatabase is the workspace geodatabase environment.

The initialized function looks like this:

(%self.getWorkspaceEnvironment => "W:/a18fb/data/mypersonalgeodatabase.mdb" and tFactsheetHochwasser => table in the personal geodatabase)

`arcpy.AddJoin_management("%s/tFactsheetHochwasser"%self.getWorkspaceEnvironment(),"KPG",
"GebaeudeKtn_BWVred1Stat","KPG","KEEP_ALL")`

If the code is executed the following error-message appears:

Failed to execute.Parameters are not valid.
The value cannot be a table

> ERROR 000840: The value is not a Raster Layer.
>
> ERROR 000840: The value is not a Raster Catalog Layer.
>
> ERROR 000840: The value is not a Mosaic Layer.
>
> Failed to execute (AddJoin)`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The solution to my issue was to create a tableView using `arcpy.MakeTableView_management()` The temporary existing View allows joining the tables each other.

Answer (score 4):

I was getting the same errors when trying to execute joins using `model builder`. The solution was to convert them to `Feature Layers` first and then join from there. I can imagine that the logic is the same using python.

Here is a link to the [question and answer that solved my problem](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/57098/why-cant-i-use-a-join-in-a-model/57100#57100).

Comment: Hi, Craig, thanks for your answer, I also have a Model doing the same spatial analysis as the script does and in the Model all works fine, but I'll try your propsed solution!