# Join multiple shapes in a workspace based on a common field

Tags: arcgis-10.0, python, modelbuilder

I’m completely stucked!!! I’m working with meteorological data (wind) but I have to arrange the data for a program to be able to process it. I have text files, two per day (one with the wind direction and the other with the speed).

I’m working with ArcGis 10, Model Builder and my little knowledge on python.

I’ve already manage to calculate in a point shapefile the date and the information, if it’s direction or speed, because it was information available only in the filename.
But now, I don’t know how to join the two files together. The fields schema I have it’s like:

POINT_ID / DATE / WIND (dir or spd) / ID_DATE (unique field) // DIR / SPD

I have like 1000 days to process and I have no idea how to continue!! The goal would be to make a join based on the ID_DATE field, so I have a unique file for each day instead of two, with the pertinent values of DIR and SPD (already calculated for each individual file).

I need to implement an attribute join with the two tables (dir and spd). The problem is that I have like 1000 different days, therefore 2000 tables to join.

I was thinking on something like reading the filename, where the date is within the name, and when finding two identical dates performing the join… So I need to read through the folder (or two separate folders with dir and spd) and indicate somehow the common attribute field or filename….

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you need to implement either [an attribute Join](http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.3/index.cfm?TopicName=About%20joining%20and%20relating%20tables) to create a composite view of your two datasets, or possibly [the Dissolve routine](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00170000005n000000) to aggregate your geometries on a common field.

If you go with the attribute join, there is [an existing answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/57098/why-cant-i-use-a-join-in-a-model) on GIS.SE that may assist you with the model setup.

Regardless as to your exact scenario, of course I'd recommend doing a couple test runs via the ArcMap or ArcCatalog toolbox, then you can experiment with adding it to your Model Builder or Python automation.